# template error expected primary-expression before '>' token

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

```
template <class T>class vector{       //this is the part for my vector, which may lead to the error shown below.
protected:
    T* arr;
    void expand(){
        if(size<capacity)return;
        if(capacity<con)capacity=con;
        T* temp=new T[capacity=2*capacity];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)temp[i]=arr[i];
        delete[] arr;
        arr=temp;
        temp=NULL;
    };
public:
    vector(int c=con,int s=0,T v=0){arr=new T[capacity=c];for(size=0;size<s;arr[size++]=v);}
    T& operator[](int r)const{return arr[r];}
    int insert(int r,const T& e){            //inserting at designated place.
        expand();
        for(int i=size;i>r;i--)arr[i]=arr[i-1];
        arr[r]=e;
        size++;
        return r;
    }
    int insert(const T& e){                  //inserting at the end
        return insert(size,e);
    }
};
template<class Tv>class vertex{
public:
    Tv data;
    vertex(Tv const& e):data(e){}
};
template<class Tv,class Te>class GraphMatrix{
private:
    vector<vertex<Tv> > v;
public:
    int insert(Tv const& vt){
    return v.insert(vertex<Tv>(vt));    //error happens here "expected primary-expression before '>' token."
    }
}
int main(){
    GraphMatrix<int,int> mail;
    int i=1;
    mail.insert(i);
}
```

I am using g++ compiler, and I got an error "expected primary-expression before '>' token".
Is it a  problem regarding template? How could I fix it? 
The problem now happens at inserting vertex(vt) into the vector written by me (my own vector).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The second error comes from a **cascade**. The first one is about the use of `vertex<Tv>` in `vertex<Tv> p`; once that fails, `p` doesn't make sense. So ignore that one; it will almost certainly go away once you've fixed the first one.

Comment: sorry I made some modification to make it clearer.

Comment: `vector::insert` doesn't take one parameter. Nor does it return `int`. As you'd know if that was your real code: https://ideone.com/RU1TFW

Comment: Yeah, I wrote my own vector which is not presented here. But it seems like the problem is more related to the vertex<Tv> inside the insert function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add a stub definition of `vector`, consistent with the way you're calling it, to your code ...

```
template <class Tv> class vector
{
public:
    int insert(Tv const &);
};

template <class Tv> class vertex
{
public:
    Tv data;
    vertex(Tv const &e) : data(e) {}
};

template <class Tv, class Te> class GraphMatrix
{
private:
    vector<vertex<Tv> > v;

public:
    int insert (Tv const &vt)
    {
        return v.insert(vertex<Tv>(vt));
    }
};

int main()
{
    GraphMatrix<int, int> mail;
    int i = 1;
    mail.insert(i);
}
```

... then it compiles (gcc, `-fsyntax-only -std=c++98 -Wall -Wextra`) with no errors or warnings.

Therefore your problem **is** with your `vector` class.  This is why we ask for minimal *complete* verifiable examples -- if the compiler's error messages don't make sense, it is likely that the problem is not what you think it is.

(Yes, the compiler *should* do a better job of explaining the problem, but that turns out to be really hard, especially for C++, whose grammar is notoriously difficult just to parse in the first place.)

Comment: Thank you @zwol! But I still have problem for my code, and I have posted all of the parts regarding my problem here (as the version after editing). Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: @jombo If I try to compile the code you provided, I get a flood of error messages, none of which is the one you are asking for help with.  I'm not going to help you any more until you actually follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @jombo Hmm, actually, the MCVE instructions are missing a key piece.  To help, I need to see a program that faithfully reproduces the problem you are having, *and no other problems*.  You must only cut *irrelevant* code out.  For instance, it's fine to remove all of the `vector` methods that are not used in the code you're asking for help with, but it's *not* fine to remove `vector` instance variables that *are* used by the `vector` methods that *are* used by the code you're asking for help with.  See?